# Channel Type dropdown not showing all channels

Tags: channel, structure

I have 2 channels that are both linked to the same category and status group. However, I tried changing/editing the status from the "options" tab after I published my and only one (the current channel that is assigned to the entry) of my two channels are listed. Is there a setting I missed somewhere to allow all of channels to display here or is this not allowed to change after the page is saved?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1739837/Screenshots/dw.png

I'm using Structure which may be causing an issue? Thoughts?

Comment: You mention the Category group and Status group, but what about Field group? All three must be the same for a channel to appear in that menu.

Answer (score 1):

As Derek says, only channels with the same field group settings will be shown in that dropdown.